# installing yarn with brew

Tags: node.js, homebrew, yarnpkg

First using brew, I installed current node LTS which is `node@14` right now

Then I symlinked node using `brew link --force node@14` since LTS versions are keg-only

Then I installed yarn with `brew install yarn` but for some reason brew installed `node@15` and after that installed yarn. `brew list` result shows `node and node@14`, the former appeared after installing yarn. Now my current node version shows `node@15`.

I want to use node LTS version and would also like yarn use that version. How do I do it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Creating a directory and linking desired version of node to that directory and installing yarn with `--ignore-dependencies` solved my problem

source: [here](https://blog.cloud-acct.com/posts/column-brew-install-yarn-ignore-dependencies/)

Comment: Additional reference with steps & commands: https://dev.to/caiangums/yarn-nodejs-lts-with-homebrew-1256

Answer (score 4):

homebrew is not a good solution for managing multiple versions of node runtime due to the fact that homebrew is always built with the latest node (in this case, node@15). As result, the package bundle can be shipped together.

Here might be the solution:

- `brew install node@14`
- configure `PATH` for node@14
- install `yarn` with `npm`